# how to enable local connection of chainlink?

Tags: chainlink

I have a custom API running on http://127.0.0.1:8080 and I have my own chainlink node running on http://127.0.0.1:6688. I get the error saying "Connections to local/private and multicast networks are disabled by default for security reasons: disallowed IP" when sending requests.

[image]

So my question is: can we enable local/private connection of chainlink? and how to do that?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70048304/11969592